# If I was travelling at the speed of light, how would I know when to stop?

Tags: speed-of-light, time

Ben is stood on Earth and I am in orbit in a ship capable of light speed, Ben and I agree that at a certain point in time, I will start orbiting earth at the speed of light (I know this is impossible, this is a thought experiment). We agree that after 10 years has passed for Ben, I will stop travelling and say hello to Ben. In this scenario, Ben has aged 10 years while, as far as I am concerned, no time has passed at all. My question is, if time does not exist for me while travelling at the speed of light, how would I know to stop after 10 years has passed for Ben? Or 100 years or a million years, how would I know when to stop!?

Comment: You cannot ignore the laws of physics then expect the laws of physics to give you a sensible answer. Your question assumes an impossible situation, i.e. you moving at $c$ relative to your friend, then expects a sensible answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise of the question is outside of the current understanding of physics

Answer (score 2):

At speed of light your existence means nothing 
Time is no concept for you
Even if millions of years pass by you would have no time to even think about when to stop

But the scenario to meet up with Ben in ten years may be possible if you travel near speed of light
Then for you only a small amount of time has passed but Ben is 10 years older